# Is there a tool for determining which @media queries are active on a third party site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify some css on a site built by another.  There are tons of different media queries and I was hoping to find a simple way to determine (while viewing the site) which media queries were being activated when.

I may be able to add some custom javascript, if necessary, but I'm hoping there's some tool or website out there that I can 'view' the site with, with the relevant information possibly overlayed in some way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use the Chrome inspector to see which media query is active on an element. While the developer tools are open you can also see pixel measurements while changing the browser windows size. These two things combined should be able to help you determine the pixel range for a media query.

Comment: Yep, developer tools are pretty great for this! If the changes are pretty subtle, sometimes I'll go into the developer tools and add in a "background-color: red", to make it reallly obvious when the media query starts/ends

Comment: There is also an app for that :) or rather [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-inspector/memcdolmmnmnleeiodllgpibdjlkbpim).